# Compare cell entry with column header in nested loops

Tags: r

I have a panel that looks like

```
df <-read.table(text="
preis10_6 akt_datum10_6 preis11_6 akt_datum11_6
1.55      10.06.2014    1.45      10.06.2014
1.56      09.06.2014    1.49      11.06.2014
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

where the odd columns (`preise`) contain prices that were collected on that day and the even columns (`akt_datum`) contain information on the data's topicality. Hence, when `df[2, 2]` is `09.06.2014` it means that the information in `df[1:2, 2]` is from the day before. I want to set these case `NA`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
# Instrall stringr for the function str_sub
require(stringr) || install.packages("stringr")

# Get indices for the columns with topicality information
spalten <- seq(2, length(df), 2)

# Loop over these columns
for (spalte in spalten) {

  # Construct the benchmark date from the column name
  splitter <- str_sub(names(df)[spalte], 10, -1)
  splitter <- strsplit(splitter, "_")
  # Account for the case where the column name is in short time format (no trailing 0)
  splitter[[1]][1] <- ifelse(nchar(splitter[[1]][1])==1,
                             paste0("0", splitter[[1]][1]),
                             splitter[[1]][1]
  )
  splitter[[1]][2] <- ifelse(nchar(splitter[[1]][2])==1,
                             paste0("0", splitter[[1]][2]),
                             splitter[[1]][2]
  )
  date <-  paste(splitter[[1]][1], splitter[[1]][2], "2014", sep=".")

  # Loop over all rows in the actual column
  for (zeile in 1:nrow(df)) {
    # and set the cell and the one before equal to NA
    ifelse(df[zeile, spalte]!=date, df[zeile, spalte] <- df[zeile, spalte-1] <- NA, "")
  }

}
```

This works but takes ages since I have in fact a 933x324 panel. That is, I have 933 prices and topicality information per day for a total of 162 days which makes 162 price-topicality pairs=324 columns.

How can I make this procedure faster?

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want? At least it produced the same output (modulo the coverted dates) as your code.

```
# Read data example
df <-read.table(text="
preis10_6 akt_datum10_6 preis11_6 akt_datum11_6
1.55      10.06.2014    1.45      10.06.2014
1.56      09.06.2014    1.49      11.06.2014
",header=TRUE,sep="")

# Convert to date (to allow for comparison between dates)
df$akt_datum10_6 <- as.Date(df$akt_datum10_6, "%d.%m.%Y")
df$akt_datum11_6 <- as.Date(df$akt_datum11_6, "%d.%m.%Y")

# Check which date is first, and substitute `NA`s
first <- df$akt_datum10_6 < df$akt_datum11_6
df[first, 1:2] <- NA
df[!first, 3:4] <- NA
print(df)
#preis10_6 akt_datum10_6 preis11_6 akt_datum11_6
#1      1.55    2014-06-10        NA          <NA>
#2        NA          <NA>      1.49    2014-06-11
```

Comment: Looks nice but how can I expand that to a case with 933 rows and 324 columns?

Comment: @MERose It should work for the case where you expand the number of rows. However, you need to modify it to do what you want for more columns. I find it unclear from your post what you want to do in that case. Maybe you clarify what you want and expand your data example a bit?

Comment: Done. It is basically more observations (rows per day) and more days (columns with prices and topicality information in a pariwise manor).